# SQL LEFT JOIN with COUNT that returns NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: one that stores the product id and one which stores total sales per product_id and per sale_date

### Table Products

```
product_id
----------
1         
2         
3
```

### Table Sales

```
product_id |  sale_date | total
-----------+------------+-------
1          | 2017-01-01 |   1
1          | 2017-02-01 |   1
1          | 2017-03-01 |   1
```

There is no sales total for product 2 and product 3.

I would like to query the sales table in order to get 0 in front of the months where there is no sale for any product id.
The result I would like to achieve is this:

```
product_id |  month     | total
-----------+------------+-------
1          | 2017-01    |   1
1          | 2017-02    |   1
1          | 2017-03    |   1
2          | 2017-01    |   0
2          | 2017-02    |   0
2          | 2017-03    |   0
3          | 2017-01    |   0
3          | 2017-02    |   0
3          | 2017-03    |   0
```

Right now what I do is this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(sale_date, "%m-%Y") as month,
       Products.product_id,
       COUNT(Sales.product_id) as total 

  FROM products Products 

LEFT OUTER JOIN sales Sales

             ON Sales.product_id = Products.product_id 

       GROUP BY Products.product_id, month
```

and what I get is:

```
product_id |  month     | total
-----------+------------+-------
1          | 2017-01    |   1
1          | 2017-02    |   1
1          | 2017-03    |   1
2          | NULL       |   0
3          | NULL       |   0
```

What should I modify to get a row for each month when there is no sale total for any product id? Thank you

Comment: I would suggest you to look at calender table.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: there is no sales, hence there is no date to convert into a month: so you have to provide the missing months

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows, then `left in` to bring in the values:

```
select p.product_id, d.sales_date,
       coalesce(s.total, 0) as total
from products p cross join
     (select distinct sales_date from sales) d left join
     sales s
     on s.product_id = p.product_id and s.sales_date = d.sales_date
order by p.product_id, d.sales_date;
```

Note:  This assumes that all the dates you want are in `sales`.  I should point out that you can use another source for the dates, if you have one, or list them explicitly.

Comment: if the the sales data is very large 'select distinct sales_date from sales` may be slow and an alternative could be to have a table of dates ("calendar table") instead.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you, the cross join was the right direction. I also create a separate calendar table for performance reasons.

Comment: I also created a separate calendar table for performance tests purposes: there was a 40% gain on the execution time (the sales table has more than 2 million line).

Answer (score 0):

Could you give a try to this query:

```
select 
 distinct p.product_id, 
 DATE_FORMAT(sale_date, "%m-%Y") as month,
 if(p.product_id <> s.product_id, 0,total) as total 
 from products p, 
sales s 
order by p.product_id
```